# Entity Framework adding a 1:1 relationship in a model causes an error on cascading deletes elsewhere

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

This is for Entity Framework Core.

First off, from reading various articles, I believe in a many to many relationship, when one of the objects is deleted, there's a cascading delete to delete any entries in the join table that map to the deleted object. But it does not delete the objects on the other side of the join table. Is this correct?

Second, here's the issue I'm hitting. The cause is adding a 1:1 relationship from a 2nd model to the same child model (I know there's no official child in a 1:1 but I view the Address model here as a child in the join).

The error I get occurs when I added the Address property to the County class.

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string? Address1 { get; set; }
    // additional properties
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Address Address { get; private set; }
    // additional properties
}

public class County
{
    public int Id { get; private set;  }
    // Adding this Address property caused the error.
    public Address Address { get; private set; }
    // additional properties
}
```

Here are the errors when I run Update-Database:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE [CountyUser] (
          [CountiesId] int NOT NULL,
          [FollowersId] int NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_CountyUser] PRIMARY KEY ([CountiesId], [FollowersId]),
          CONSTRAINT [FK_CountyUser_Counties_CountiesId] FOREIGN KEY ([CountiesId]) REFERENCES [Counties] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT [FK_CountyUser_Users_FollowersId] FOREIGN KEY ([FollowersId]) REFERENCES [Users] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
      );
Failed executing DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [CountyUser] (
    [CountiesId] int NOT NULL,
    [FollowersId] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CountyUser] PRIMARY KEY ([CountiesId], [FollowersId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CountyUser_Counties_CountiesId] FOREIGN KEY ([CountiesId]) REFERENCES [Counties] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CountyUser_Users_FollowersId] FOREIGN KEY ([FollowersId]) REFERENCES [Users] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

and

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_CountyUser_Users_FollowersId' on table 'CountyUser' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

I read this as saying the cascading delete County => User and/or User => County is a problem not because of deleting County or User, but because both then want to delete Address as that's a 1:1 relationship. Is this correct?

And if so, no Address record will be shared. So can I tell EF not to worry, delete the associated Address object and everything will be fine?

If not, how do I tell it with fluent to, I assume, not delete the Address record? Or is there some other way I should set it in fluent?

I already have code to delete another associated record for a 1:many case EF gets confused over in MyDbContext.SaveChanges()/SaveChangesAsync() so easy to add some more processing there if needed.

Comment: Maybe you need just [Owned entity type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, @stevepy answer got me 90% of the way there and want to give him credit.

I did the following, and same for State too:

```
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(u => u.Address)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<User>("AddressId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
    }
}
```

And then in MyDbContext I override `SaveChanges()` and `SaveChangesAsync()` and in those, do the following (again, for State too):

```
var deletedUsers = ChangeTracker.Entries<User>()
    .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted)
    .Select(e => e.Entity).ToList<User>();

foreach (var user in deletedUsers)
{
    // remove the user.Address record
    var address = await Addresses.Where<Address>(a => a.Id == user.AddressId)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (address != null)
        Addresses.Remove(address);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can configure EF to use a one-to-one relationship between User and Address and County and Address in that manner where each table holds an AddressID for their respective address, as far as the database is concerned, if there is a common Address table with these records pointing FKs at a row, these are actually a Many-to-One relationship which will likely cause issues with the cycling cascade. While you might insist that one address would only ever be associated to a single user *or* a single county, there is little to nothing in the DB to enforce this. Two user records could be given the same AddressID, (unless we also put a unique constraint on User.AddressID) but the same AddressID could end up in a County and User record.

The safest option to do this form of one-to-one relationship is having the address columns embedded in their respective table. An option available in EF Core to facilitate this nicely with an Address entity is to use Owned entities which I believe could extend a common Address entity.

```
public class UserAddress : Address
{ }

public class CountyAddress : Address
{ }
```

Where a User is configured to OwnsOne UserAddress. From the code perspective you have an Address object for each top level entity to encompass the common set of address fields. In the database, these can either be embedded in their respective parent tables (Address columns within User and County respectively) or separate tables, I.e. UserAddress and CountyAddress respectively. While the naming convention for UserAddress might imply a many-to-many relationship between User and Address, it might be more clear as "AddressForUser" and "AddressForCounty". With separate tables or embedded columns, the one-to-one owned nature of this relationship can be done in a way to keep the database happy.

Comment: Thank you, your answer got me 90% of the way there. Can't do OwnsOne() because two different parent models can't both own the same child.

Comment: Correct, you cannot have both own Address, but User can own an AddressForUser while County owns AddressForCounty, whether both of those can extend an "Address" entity or not would need some testing to ensure EF isn't treating that as a TPH inheritance. (putting both in a single Address table) They would need to be separate tables or embedded within the respective tables.

Answer (score 0):

There are few solution to this issue.

Firstly, I believe in your current scheme the the relationship Foreign key is located on `Address` table, which is not correct approach.

This will create two shadow FK on Address table which is CountyId and UserId, which mean every single address must have this two parent.

The correct way is the Foreign Key should be in User and County table effectively promoting `Address`as the parent entity for the relationship. Try configure your fluent API like this.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
        .HasMany<County>()
        .WithOne(e => e.Address);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
        .HasMany<User>()
        .WithOne(e => e.Address);
}
```

This will create a shadow nullable FK AddressId from User/County side of relationship rather than `Address` side of relationship.

Noted that I purposely set one to many relationship between address and user /County since by logic one Address can be shared by many user/County, even though from our coding side they may have their own respective row in the table  address anyway.

Second approach : Since address to the User and County is one to one relationship, you can also easily configure `Address` as Owned datatype :

```
[Owned]
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string? Address1 { get; set; }
    // additional properties
}
```

This will effectively pull all the column from the Address table and put it inside its parent table of `County` and `User` .

> If not, how do I tell it with fluent to, I assume, not delete the Address record? Or is there some other way I should set it in fluent?

To answer this question, if you are using my first approach to this answer, the address table will never be automatically delete because it is the principal side of the relationship.

> I read this as saying the cascading delete County => User and/or User => County is a problem not because of deleting County or User, but because both then want to delete Address as that's a 1:1 relationship. Is this correct?

I believe that is the reason as well

> And if so, no Address record will be shared. So can I tell EF not to worry, delete the associated Address object and everything will be fine?

> If not, how do I tell it with fluent to, I assume, not delete the Address record? Or is there some other way I should set it in fluent?

If you still prefer Address as the Child entity, I believe you can do this by

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string? Address1 { get; set; }
    public int? CountyId { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    // additional properties
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
        .HasOne<County>()
        .WithOne(e => e.Address)
        .HasForeignKey<Address>(e => e.CountyId)
        .IsRequired(false)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
        .HasOne<User>()
        .WithOne(e => e.Address)
        .HasForeignKey<Address>(e => e.UserId)
        .IsRequired(false)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
}
```

By using this Way, EF Core will determine which Parent the Address belong to by checking which column is not null between `CountyId` and `UserId`. So one the column will have value, while the second one will be Null. You can also set OnDeleteCascade also to see if it work, but I am not really sure about this.

But still this approach is not very beautiful and I personally would lke to suggest that Address should be the parent rather than Child. This way in future if any new table want to have an address, the new table can just add the FK `AddressId` on their side, and no changes from table Address is needed. Imagine having hundred of table each need an address when your application grow, will it make sense to keep adding the FK on Address table to refer to each new parent table? The better approach is just to add an extra AddressId on each of the new table to refer to the AddressId and we can move on with life to solve other problem. :)